# PHP preg_replace function causing net::ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace certain noscript tags inside a large HTML document using preg_replace, the regex I am using is as follows.

```
$regex = '/<noscript><iframe(.?)+width="'.$width.'"(.?)+height="'.$height.'"(.?)+<\/iframe><\/noscript>/m';
$html = preg_replace($regex, $customTag, $html);
```

It constantly resets the connection to my server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your PHP log, i don't see why a `preg_replace()` would reset your connection. Also check for php_ini values `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` if your files are huge.

Comment: already did, max execution time is 120 sec and memory limit is 520M, it did not work.

Comment: Try using `(.+?)` instead of  `(.?)+`

Comment: I get your point @ibarros, Now I know why it took so long to get the result back that server reset the connection, will definitely give it a try, please make it an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You should consider DOM manipulation for tasks such as this rather than regex.

Comment: I did use symfony DOMCrawler but it can only traverse DOM, cannot modify it as I want to. If you know any library suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `(.?)+` to `(.+?)`

- `(.+?)` Will match any character (except newline) in an ungreedy manner.